# Check if XML node name contains a letter using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

This is not the only question about this but I could not figure out from the other solutions why my code is wrong. This is for an assignment and I have most of it figured out but I cannot understand why the condition never evaluates to true. If I make up a dummy clause such as `contains('a', 'a')` or even `1=1` then I can see the proper output (unfiltered by the condition, obviously, however).

Also, if I just try to output the name of the current element using `<xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />` nothing is output. Obviously there is something I am not getting here but it's eluding me. Any clue ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".">
        <xsl:if test="contains(name(.),'a')">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this case, the XML schema does not matter at all. I know that some elements contain the letter a (including the root element).

Also why is it that when I call `<xsl:value-of select="name(node())" />` I get the name of the XSLT file node ("xsl:stylesheet") and not the name of the current node in the file that is being processed by my XSLT document ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am surprised you are not getting an error when you run your XSLT, because when I try it using Mircosoft's XSLT processing I get the error *"Only 'child' and 'attribute' axes are allowed in a pattern outside predicates."*. This is because in XPath a dot is an abbreviation for the context node.

I am wondering if the XSLT processing you are using is matching the top-level document node with `match="."` (similar to doing match="/") which would explain why you are not getting any output.

In any case, you really do need `<xsl:template match="*">` here, and not `<xsl:template match="." />`

But what you really should be doing to solve the problem is building upon the XSLT [Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which is a fundamental design pattern in XSLT. On its own it copies all the existing nodes in the input XML, but you can then just add extra template matching for the cases you need.

In your case, you say you want to copy only elements containing an 'a' in the name. Well, think of it in reverse, and say, in that case, you "don't" want to copy elements which don't have an 'a' in their name. Thus, all you need to add to the identity transform is this template

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(contains(name(), 'a'))]" />
```

As an aside, you don't really need your initial template for "/" here

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT has the concept of built-in templates, which are used when there is not an explicit template in the XSLT. These built in templates will output the text for text nodes, and for other nodes it will just continue processing the children (without copying the node). So, all the template for "/" is doing is what the built-in template would do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some basic concepts.

You have `match='.'` and if you want to match all elements you need `match='*'`.

And since you are asking for the name of the first child node of the current node, and you are getting `xsl:stylesheet`, that tells me that you are executing that instruction with the stylesheet as your input XML and the current node as the root node.

And I foresee problems in that if the document element doesn't contain an 'a', you are doing nothing to process the rest of the document.

Perhaps it would help if you described what your assignment is, rather than show us what doesn't work ... but, then again, if someone gives you the answer then you won't have been helped at all, really.

Comment: The assignment asks us to copy only elements containing the letter a in their name. If an element does not contain an a, you need to also flush out all its children. That's why I use `match='.'`, that allows me to then use `<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()" />` to go one level deeper if the current level satisfies the condition. What I am now having trouble with is that if the condition is not satisfied at one point, the execution stops. This is why my output was always empty. It found xml:stylesheet first and then skipped the rest.

Comment: If it found `xsl:stylesheet` first, then your invocation is messed up.  You are invoking your stylesheet with a stylesheet as input data.  You don't show in your question what your input data is.  If it does, indeed, have `xml:stylesheet` as its document element, then your requirement to "flush out all its children" is satisfied when you have an empty output.  BTW, when `select=` is omitted from `<xsl:apply-templates/>` that is an abbreviation for `select="child::node()"`.